# How to convert an integer to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

What would be the most simple way to convert an integer to an array of numbers?

Example:

`2468` should result in `array(2,4,6,8)`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) and [`intval`](http://php.net/intval):

```
$number = 2468;

    $array  = array_map('intval', str_split($number));

var_dump($array);
```

Which will give the following output:

```
array(4) {
  [0] => int(2)
  [1] => int(4)
  [2] => int(6)
  [3] => int(8)
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/HKAF6ZXR)

Comment: Ya. Just convert the int value to a string and split it.

Comment: `str_split` does convert to string already. However the output wasn't an array of integers,, so this needed actually some conversion.

Answer (score 8):

use str_split() function

```
$array = str_split($str);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Answer (score 7):

You can cut-off the last digit by taking the number modulo 10.

**Don't tell it to anyone!**

```
do 
{
    $array.add(num % 10);
    num = num / 10;
}
while (num != 0);
```

Comment: Wait, wha...?  `Don't tell it to anyone`?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

[Example #2 Splitting a string into component characters](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#refsect1-function.preg-split-examples)

```
$str = 'string';
$chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: str_split() from the other answeres would perform much better (i'll guess).