# How to remove the last digit of an integer? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, integer

What would be the best way to remove the last digit of an integer in a MySQL query??

I'm working on a genealogy project. Assuming the `father_id` would be

```
10001
```

the kids would then be

```
100011
100012
100013
```

ect.

I get the `father_ID` and I need to be able to get all of his children

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Father_ID LIKE '$F_ID%'
```

But it didn't work.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118964/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-an-array-in-php) on converting an integer into an array, I think that could help some way but I dont know what I would do after that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't want to remove the last digit of an Integer. Instead you want to match any Integer with a fixed prefix and a variable last digit.

Comment: What happens if a father (or mother) has more than 10 children?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure whether this is a good way to build a family tree at all. Using a "father ID" like you do

- allows  tracking one parent only - not really suitable for any serious ancestry research
- makes changes difficult - you'll have to re-calculate the entire ID if a correction is made
- has the problem @stefgosselin mentions - what about families with more than 10 kids?

The only upside I can see is that it's terribly easy to query all descendants of one ancestor, but that alone isn't worth it IMO.

I would use normal auto-increment IDs, and give each record a `parent` column (or `father` and `mother`, of course, or to account for  same-gender parents, `parent1` and `parent2`). That column would contain the ID of the parent record.

Then you could simply do queries like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE father = `530`
```

querying ancestors would become a bit tougher, but everything else becomes much easier.

Comment: i have acually simplified for the purpose of getting my main question answered
i have a personal ID, mother_ID, Father_ID, Family_ID... ect. all for one row

Comment: @user that sounds awfully complicated. An approach with a parent column might work better.

Comment: i need to have all these for various reasons, (such as creating visuals)

Comment: Add to that the fact that the mother is generally identifiable, the father isn't always so... so why follow the id trail down the paternal branch, rather than the maternal... but I'd recommend using Pekka's suggestion of a straight autoincrement id, with links in your record to father_id and mother_id

Comment: @user you could create visuals with the column model as well, it's just more work to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the actual schema of your database you have basically two options:

1. Match the Integer as a string.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE father_id LIKE '${f_id}%';
   ```
2. Match the Integer as numeric value.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE father_id >= $f_id * 10 AND father_id < ($f_id + 1) * 10;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL was wrong, the correct syntax is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Father_ID LIKE '$F_ID%'
```

Comment: I am looking into it, but in the worst case he would have to cast it

Comment: `LIKE` matches strings. So no, it won't work on numbers. *But* since you're not actually using the type of the variable and you're using `$f_id` as a string, it'll work.

Comment: @joschi: just tried on MySQL 5.x it works, I think MySQL is kind enough to automatically do the cast in string

Comment: are you sure you used `"` so PHP replace the `$F_ID`?

Comment: You have to distinguish between "it works on integers" and "it works by casting numbers to strings". In this case it's the latter and it has some implications. Docs on pattern matching with `LIKE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: @joschi: In MySQL, LIKE is permitted on numeric expressions. (This is an extension to the standard SQL LIKE.)

Comment: @RageZ: In MySQL, it implicitly casts the number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I get mixed up with my languages so please excuse me if this is invalid. Try the following:

```
floor(number / 10);
```