# how to convert php number string into number array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to compare each digit of a number array. Like: 5450...i want to compare each of the digit such as: 5,4,5,0 individually with other number.for that i want to convert this number string in number array.how to do this?

Comment: result will be like this `Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 0)`

Comment: [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118964/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-an-array-in-php

Comment: thanks 웃웃웃웃웃, Harshal Mahajan... thanks @MarkBaker for your first answer. Actually sometimes it needs to get help in small cases and all people are not genius like you. I am new in stack overflaw. I dont' understand what do you mean by off topic. But if you think you genius only answer the talf questions, why did you answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to convert the string in to Array

For example:

```
<?php
$str="5450";
$arr=str_split($str);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg-split` - see example two here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php